How to prove that $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin kx}{k^z} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{z-1}e^t\sin x}{1–2e^t\cos x+e^{2t}}dt? $
I need it to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin k}{k^3} = \frac{2\pi^2-3\pi+1}{12}$

Please use a high-level tag like "ca.classical-analysis-and-odes". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Using the decomposition
$$\frac{e^t\sin x}{1–2e^t\cos x+e^{2t}}
=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{t+ix}}-\frac{1}{1-e^{t-ix}}\right),$$
we obtain for $\Re(z)>1$ (using the Bose-Einstein integral) that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{z-1}e^t\sin x}{1–2e^t\cos x+e^{2t}}\,dt
&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\mathrm{Li}_z(e^{ix})-\mathrm{Li}_z(e^{-ix})\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{k^z}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^z}.\end{align*}
